# LinkLabel no underline - Compact Framework

Tags: c#, winforms, compact-framework, windows-ce

I am developing a Windows CE app with Microsoft Compact Framework. I have to use a LinkLabel and it has to be white and no underline.

So in the designer, I modified font color by white and unchecked "underline" in the font dialog.

However, when I run the application, the font is still blue and underlined.

Is there a way to remove the underline of a LinkLabel and change its color?

Comment: Kamal Gupta's answer should probably be the accepted one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *wont be visible in the designer at Design-Time* **but will be correct in Runtime**.

Otherwise do it in Code (which should be the same as the designers code):

```
Font f = LinkLabel1.Font; 
LinkLabel1.Font = New Font(f, f.Style && !FontStyle.Underline)
```

Comment: Actually, even in runtime, LinkLabekl is still blue and underlined... However, now I can't test on device, I test on desktop. Maybe it will be correct on device?

Comment: @axvo Is the issue resolved on the device or is further troubleshooting required?

Comment: I can't test on the device because I don't have it yet. Not sure I'll get it before 5 or 6 days. When I will able to test, I'll tell you if it's resolved

Comment: It finally works. On device, LinkLabel has the expected design. So it's just a desktop issue. Thanks Jeremy

Answer (score 21):

You can use `LinkBehavior`:

```cs
Me.linkLabel1.LinkBehavior = System.Windows.Forms.LinkBehavior.NeverUnderline;
```

[image]

Comment: Works fine even at design time and I guess it's the proper way to do that.